# angular get selected option value and insert into link

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to populate a link via a selected option in a dropdown.  I don't know how I would get the value from the about option and not have it repeat.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="horsepower=[
{hp:'15',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/15-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressor-system-230-3-60-total-air-system.html'},
{hp:'20',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/20-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html'}]">


<select>
  <option ng-repeat="x in horsepower" value="{{ x.value}}" ng-model="hp">{{ x.hp}}</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<!-- get the selected value of select -->
<a ng-href="{{}}">
buy
</a>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/blynn17/171g1x2z/1/

Comment: I dont really understand the question: what are you trying to do? What is the specific problem? What is being repeated? I have checked the fiddle, but didnt get any wiser...

Comment: I'm trying to populate the link with the correct value associated to the selected option.

Comment: So if the option is 15 then the link at the bottom get the row value.

Comment: Is there a way to have it selected="selected" for the first <option> ?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `ng-options` in `select` tag and use the `ng-model` for calling the selected value in your `href`

`<select  ng-options="x as x.hp for x in horsepower" value="{{ x.value}}" ng-model="hp">`

Demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/bhedvue7/

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
$scope.test = function(value){
  $scope.href= value;
  
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="horsepower=[
{hp:'15',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/15-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressor-system-230-3-60-total-air-system.html'},
{hp:'20',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/20-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html'}]">

<select ng-model="hp" ng-options="x.value as x.hp for x in horsepower" ng-change="test(hp)"></select>

<br/><br/>
<!-- get the selected value of select -->
<a ng-href="{{href}}">
buy
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/171g1x2z/2/)

Use `ngOptions` instead of `ngRepeat` and use `ngModel` on the `select` tag.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you have put the ng-model on the wrong place, you should put it on the select and not the option.
other than that you should use the hp variable inside the href and thats it there you go !

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="horsepower=[
{hp:'15',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/15-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressor-system-230-3-60-total-air-system.html'},
{hp:'20',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/20-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html'}]">


<select  ng-model="hp">
  <option ng-repeat="x in horsepower" value="{{ x.value}}">{{ x.hp}}</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<!-- get the selected value of select -->
<a href="{{hp}}">
buy {{hp}}
</a>

</div>
```

you can learn more about angular and select here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above but slightly cleaner

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="horsepower=[
{hp:'15',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/15-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressor-system-230-3-60-total-air-system.html'},
{hp:'20',value:'https://www.compressorworld.com/20-hp-rotary-screw-air-compressors-complete-air-system-lifetime-airend-warranty.html'}]">


<select ng-options="x.hp for x in horsepower" ng-model="hp"></select>
<br/><br/>
<!-- get the selected value of select -->
<a ng-href="{{hp.value}}">
buy
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it selected="selected" for the first <option> ?

Comment: Yes, try adding `hp=horsepower[0]` at the end of your ng-init