# Angularjs use scope value as href

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

A quick question, how can I get the link to refer to post.id, this what I have not dosn't work. post.id has a existing value.

```
<a href={{post.id}}><h2 class="text-center">{{post[0].title}}</h2></a>
```

Comment: my be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156415/angular-get-selected-option-value-and-insert-into-link/36156771#36156771

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `ngHref` for this kind of use:

Examples:

```
<input ng-model="value" /><br />
<a id="link-1" href ng-click="value = 1">link 1</a> (link, don't reload)<br />
<a id="link-2" href="" ng-click="value = 2">link 2</a> (link, don't reload)<br />
<a id="link-3" ng-href="/{{'123'}}">link 3</a> (link, reload!)<br />
<a id="link-4" href="" name="xx" ng-click="value = 4">anchor</a> (link, don't reload)<br />
<a id="link-5" name="xxx" ng-click="value = 5">anchor</a> (no link)<br />
<a id="link-6" ng-href="{{value}}">link</a> (link, change location)
```

[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) (Angular docs).

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer.